# To connect windows DB2 via Linux server

Tags: db2

I am new to DB2 database. I have a database created in windows shared platform and have to connect them using Linux servers. How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you followed the installation instructions on database connectivity?

Comment: I've installed DB2 client on Linux machine and executed the below command                                                                                            db2 => CONNECT TO hostname:port/dbname USER userid USING password
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "hostname:port/dbname" was found following
"TO".  Expected tokens may include:  "<database-alias>".  SQLSTATE=42601